# Enviar email personalizado al resetaear la contraseña en Django

Tags: python, django, email

Estoy tratando de hacer el reset de la contrasenña con Django. El email de reset se envía pero su contenido no es válido. Lo que recibo es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Evidentemente, **example.com** no es mi dominio y los enlaces no funcionan. A parte, me gustaría modificar el texto que se envía por defecto.
En el archivo **settings.py** tengo esta configuración

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'miemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'contraseña'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Notificación <miemail@gmail.com>'
```

Answer (score 2):

He podido cambiar el nombre del dominio. Para lograrlo:

En el archivo **settings.py** definir la variable `SITE_ID = 1` . El **1** indica la clave primaria en la tabla **django_sites** de nuestra base de datos, dónde se encontrará el nombre de dominio que hayamos estableceido.

Añadir a `INSTALLED_APPS` esto `'django.contrib.sites'`.

Seguidamente, hacemos las migraciones `python manage.py migrate`

Accedemos al panel de administracion `dominio.com/admin`

Y establecemos en el apartado **Sites** el nombre de nuestro dominio

Answer (score 0):

Hazle override a la plantilla. Para ello coloca la tuya en `templates/registration/password_reset_email.html` con el contenido que desees. Tienes disponible la variable `user` en la plantilla, es decir, `{{ user.username }}`, por ejemplo.

El framework Django Sites únicamente se recomienda usar si tienes varios dominios, no uno.